# Display only duplicate lines, ignoring the first x spaces per line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with numbered lines. The numbers are taking up the first 7 spaces each line. I want to check the remainder of the line for duplicates and only output the duplicates.

For example, my file might be:

```
     1 abcde
     2 12345789 
     3 6789   
     4 000000
     5 abcde
```

In which case I would want my output to be:

```
     1 abcde
     5 abcde
```

Output formatting doesn't matter much of course, though it'd be great if the duplicate strings were matched together so I can find them more easily.

I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` the file on the second field, and tell GNU `uniq` to skip the first 7 characters (`-s 7`), telling  it print repeated lines (`-D`):

```
$ sort -k2,2 foo | uniq -Ds 7
     1 abcde
     5 abcde
```

Comment: @don_crissti The question originally had a `linux` tag, which you nuked, so I can safely assume GNU `uniq`.

Comment: @don_crissti Oh, I get it now. You should post that that as answer.

Comment: This is great! Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @muru Linux doesn't imply GNU uniq. **Non-embedded** Linux does. Regarding tags, we have a policy of not using OS tags unless the question is specific to a particular OS, which this one isn't.